# Text Game - Morality Tracker/Global variable - Python

Tags: python, global

My code is uploaded on githib here:

https://github.com/GameWylder/MonolithGame/blob/Alpha/QfS%200.1.2a.py

So, what I'm trying to do is use a Global variable to track "Morality".

Now, it's not true moral choices, but I want to use it to track a players choices.

I basically have this setup:

```
morality = 0

def pick():
    while True:
        choice = input("")
        if choice == "Hesitate":
            hesitate() #hesitate() is defined already, i just didn't include it to save space.
            morality = 1
            break
        elif choice == "Walk":
            walk() #again, walk() is previously defined.
            morality = 2
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Input")
#+#+#+#+#+#+#+#+#+#+#+#+#+#
#Clean Up
#+#+#+#+#+#+#+#+#+#+#+#+#+#

pick()
print(morality) #This is to see if the morality worked.
```

Sadly, it doesn't work. How can I properly set this up?

(My set up is this; the first choice will set the first number, 1 or 2, then the second choice sets the first decimal to either #.1 or #.2, then the third will do #.#1 or #.#2 etc, etc.)

What I mean by "it doesn't work" is this

```
>>>What's your choice?
Walk
>>>
>>>You Walk
>>>0
```

when it should be like

```
>>>What's your choice?
walk
>>>
>>>You Walk
>>>2
```

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work*?

Comment: @traceur it wouldn't print either 1 or 2 it would print 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform an assignment to a variable name within a function, it will create a local variable unless the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) is used.  Try adding the following line to the top of your `pick` function:

```
global morality
```

Or better yet, just have your `pick` function return the morality value and then when you make the call use `morality = pick()`.

For a more thorough explanation of the `global` statement, see this blog post:
http://freepythontips.wordpress.com/2013/07/28/the-use-of-return-and-global-keywords/

Comment: I have tried that actually. Sadly it just returns the same problem.

Comment: @GameWylder Could you edit your question with the code where you try this?  Maybe I can spot something.

Comment: the link at the top brings you to a copy of my code on github.

Comment: @GameWylder You have a typo in `addmoral`: you set `choicepth`, not `choicepath`, to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Just to simplify your problem, look at this code:

```
morality = 0
def foo():
    morality = 99
    print "in foo:", morality

print "morality before foo:", morality
foo()
print "morality after foo:", morality
```

Which produces the output:

```
morality before foo: 0
in foo: 99
morality after foo: 0
```

Now try it with this version of `foo()`:

```
def foo():
    global morality
    morality = 99
    print "in foo:", morality
```

I think the same issue applies to your code.